# Создать шаблоны команд Linux

Tags: linux, ssh

Имеется сервер Linux. Работаю через ssh. Очень часто приходится выполнять команды, например такую `ps aux | grep php`

Вопрос, можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы команда `ps-php` соответствовала `ps aux | grep php`

Comment: Гуглить "alias". Например: alias ps-php='ps aux | grep php'

Comment: Почему не `man pgrep`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Установка

```
alias ps-php='ps aux | grep php'
```

Удаление

```
unalias ps-php
```

Список

```
alias -p
```

Посмотреть один алиас

```
alias ps-php
```

Сохранить всё в bash

```
alias -p >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: А почему `>>` а не `>`? Он разве содержимое файла в свой листинг не выведет?

Comment: @Qwertiy, чтобы перезаписать `.bashrc`? Там куча другого может быть. Не только алиасы.

Comment: >> - добавить к файлу, > - перезаписать весь файл

Answer (score 4):

делается с помощью алиасов.

`alias <сокращенное имя>='<команда>'`

Например

`alias ps-php='ps aux | grep php'`

Comment: то что нужно! спасибо! а как удалить алиас?

Comment: только не забудь их потом сохранить в bashrc

Comment: @Денис переподключись

Comment: @eri то есть после переподключения алиасы удаляются? а сохранить покуда сам их не удалишь не как ?

Comment: @Денис расписал отдельно